# Firefox flex - How to prevent flex items from growing too tall with flex-direction: column

Tags: css, flexbox

I have been working on flex layout and have run into an issue against Firefox and IE11.

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/liuyi/pen/eMLpXJ) to show to show the issue.

**Screenshot**

[image: Chrome(left), Firefox(right)]
*Chrome(left), Firefox(right)*

**Description**

The expected behavior is *header* and *footer* are always visible to user, and *Content* area uses `overflow-y: auto` to scroll its innerContent if needed. The problem is ***Firefox*** and ***Internet Explorer*** allow content area to grow as tall as its innerContent, rather then stay the size the flex box spec says it should be. In other words, once add enough content to the content container rather than kicking the scrollbars the content container will just keep getting taller, then break the layout entirely.

- I know using explicit height for content container is a workaround, but it is not a prefer or valid solution for us.
- Due to the nature of our layout being flexible we can't just use something like percentages.

Comment: Not an answer but a tip for others in the future - you can avoid some of the problems with `flex-direction: column;` by leaving it at default (row), adding flex-wrap and making the children `width: 100%;` https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/614hkcsm/

Comment: Hastig, interesting, I will try and keep update with your trick.

Comment: @Hastig Zusammenstellen I just try with *row*, *wrap* and *100% width*, seems not working for this case. Anyway, your idea might be useful for others:)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: auto;` to the `.main` div

```
.container .innerContainer .main {
    background-color: #A3845D;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto; /*<< added */
}
```

Works fine on my version of FF (59.0.2) can't check in IE currently.

Comment: This answer really saves lots of my time, actually, I tried to solve it over several days. That worked for my Firefox 59.0.2, I will validate with IE11 later and keep update here.

Comment: Both Internet Explorer 11(11.0.9600.17843) and Safari 11.1(13605.1.33.1.2) work fine.

Comment: It's ridiculous but this actually works even if ".main" doesn't get the scrollbar but one of its siblings should/does.

Comment: This fixes the height problem, but it causes scrolling to occur within the container. Anyway to make the height of a flex container match the height of the flex items within it, but _not_ have a scroll bar?

Answer (score 5):

**NOTICE** - *Fecosos gave the right answer and beat me to it by a long time. I'll leave up my code as it strips out a lot of the unnecessary stuff.*

---

Apologies for butchering your code but this seems to work in FF and Chrome. No idea about IE. (I recall Safari giving me the most problems but I forget if it was with this specific issue.)

Note - I copied this code from an app where I was having a similar problem and I never figured out why the problem existed, I recall just trial and erroring different things until I got something that worked.

**pen**

https://codepen.io/nooble/pen/GxXyzb

**code**

```js
var rightPanel = document.getElementById("rightPanel");
for(var loop = 0; loop < 50; loop++) {
    var contentNode = document.createElement("div");
    contentNode.className = "content";
    contentNode.innerText = "Content";
    rightPanel.appendChild(contentNode);
}
```

```css
* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto; /* this is important */
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 100px;
}
.right {
  flex: 2;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto; /* this is important */
}
/* unnecessary styling stuff below */
body { background-color: grey; } .header { background-color: red; } .navigator { background-color: #5E6074; } .main { background-color: #A3845D; } .left { background-color: #808080; } .right { background-color: #78AB86; } .content { background-color: #406C98; } .footer { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="navigator">Navigator</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right" id="rightPanel">    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice work with the clean up, thanks for the positivity.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, really positivity.